# Match dates and id between data.frames only once

Tags: r

Have 2 example databases as follows

```
id<-c(1,2,3,1,4,3,5)
date<-c("2011-1-1","2011-1-1","2011-2-2","2012-3-3","2012-4-4","2012-5-5","2012-6-6")
d<-data.frame(cbind(id,date))
colnames(d)<-c("id","date")
d$w<-do.call(paste,c(d[c("id","date")],sep=" "))

id<-c(7,8,9,10,7,10,8,10,11,12)
date<-c("2011-1-1","2011-1-1","2011-2-2","2012-3-3","2012-3-3","2012-4-4","2012-4-4","2012-5-5","2012-6-6","2012-6-6")
contr<-data.frame(cbind(id,date))
colnames(contr)<-c("id","date")
contr$w<-do.call(paste,c(contr[c("id","date")],sep=" "))
```

Consider that id and dates are repeated in both datasets but d$id are all different from contr$id and that all contr$date are %in% d$date
What I want is y that is a vector including ONE contr$w FOR EACH d$id that have a contr$date%in%d$date

I have tried this which does not work but I am sure there must be a much easier,simpler=better way to do it.

```
y<-0
for(i in length(levels(factor(d$w)))){
   for(j in length(levels(factor(contr$w)))){
     z<-ifelse(d$date[i]==contr$date[j],contr$w[j],NA)
     y<-c(y,z)
     y<-subset(y,!is.na(y))
  }
}
```

Anyone can help?
Many thanks,
Marco

Comment: `contr$w[ match( contr$date , d$date ) ]`

Comment: Thanks but this results in contr$w (all contr$date are %in% d$date, this way we kept all data in contr).

Comment: Well in your example all `d$date` are `%in%` `contr$date` too! Perhaps you should update the example and show the expected output for `y`. It would help.

Comment: They are the same. I created contr from a larger dataset extracting only data where date matched d (d is a much smaller dataset and all dates in d are in contr as well. What I am trying to obtain is ONE value of contr$w (that is one date for each id in contr). I was just thinking that maybe I extract a randomised sample of contr$date for each contr$id. That might be another way to look at it?

Comment: Ok, `match()` *returns a vector of the positions of **(first)** matches of its first argument in its second*. We use the return value from `match()` as an index vector. So for each date it *is* getting one value. I'm sorry if I fail to understand you still.

Comment: Sorry @SimonO'Hanlon if I fail to explain myself. I have been rethinking how to do this and in the end a random sample of a date per id worked just fine. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have written now a loop that does this (the previous answer did not work as some cases in d did not have a matching date in contr). It is very slow but it does exactly what I wanted

```
for(i in 1:length(d$rownames)){
   if(TRUE%in%levels(factor(contr$w%in%d$w[i]))==TRUE){
       control.2$rownames[i]<-sample(contr$rownames[ctr$w==d$w[i]],1)
       contr<-contr[!contr$rownames%in%control.2$rownames[i],]
}else{
       z<-contr[contr$practice==d$practice[i],]
       z$tempo<-abs(difftime(z$date,d$date[i],units="days"))
       z<-z[!is.na(z$tempo),]
       z<-z[z$tempo==min(z$tempo),]
       control.2$rownames[i]<-sample(z$rownames,1)
       contr<-contr[!contr$rownames%in%control.2$rownames[i],]
  }
}
```

Not the best code I am sure, but it works. The second look accounts for the few cases where there was no case with a matching date so I chose the sampled() one with the closest date. If you can come up with a faster version, that would be nice. My datasets are about d=~5K rows and contr=~2.5 million rows and it takes roughly 2 hours to run. Painful but worth the wait!

Answer (score 0):

This did what I wanted, maybe I was not clear enough in my explanation. I just wanted a random date per id (then I can create the w column). I have sorted this by using a solution from this other question:

[Random row selection in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010220/random-row-selection-in-r)

Many t
hanks for the effort anyway!
Marco

Comment: Actually I notice that this did not do what I wanted. I have written a loop to do it and it works.for(i in 1:length(d$rownames)){
  if(TRUE%in%levels(factor(ctr$pd%in%d$pd[i]))==TRUE){
    control.2$rownames[i]<-sample(ctr$rownames[ctr$pd==d$pd[i]],1)
    ctr<-ctr[!ctr$rownames%in%control.2$rownames[i],]
  }else{
    z<-ctr[ctr$practice==d$practice[i],]
    z$tempo<-abs(difftime(z$date,d$date[i],units="days"))
    z<-z[!is.na(z$tempo),]
    z<-z[z$tempo==min(z$tempo),]
    control.2$rownames[i]<-sample(z$rownames,1)
    ctr<-ctr[!ctr$rownames%in%control.2$rownames[i],]
  }
}